# seek bar and media player android

Tags: android, android-studio, development-environment

I am Making a very simple video player app with play/pause button and a seek bar.
But when I change position of seek bar the video starts playing from starting.
I have tried many solutions to do this but I cannot resolve this.
Please anybody may help me to resolve this.
I am learning the android development and I am a beginner So please give me some tips if you can.

```
package com.example.videoplayer;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.kh);
        surfaceView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(@NonNull SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(@NonNull SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(@NonNull SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

            }
        });
        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if(fromUser){
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    button.setText("play");
                     }
                else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    button.setText("pause");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if (fromUser) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress * 1000);
    }
}
```